# getCheckedRadioButtonId just gives me nullpoint exception

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

Im having some issues, i have two Groups of Radiobuttons in my XML which has handling in an activity. It just crashes with nullpoint exception on line 48:
int languangeId = languageGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

I have set a "default" checked button in the XML to one of the buttons in the buttongroup,
So why doesnt it get an valid value?:(

```
public class FirstTimeSelectMenu extends Activity{

private RadioGroup languageGroup;
private RadioGroup storageGroup;
private Button okButton;
private String getStorage;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_time_run);

    languageGroup = (RadioGroup)this.findViewById(R.id.languageGroup);
    storageGroup = (RadioGroup)this.findViewById(R.id.storageGroup);
    okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.okBtn);



    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




            int languangeId = languageGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int storageId = storageGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton languageb = (RadioButton)findViewById(languangeId);
            RadioButton storageb = (RadioButton)findViewById(storageId);

            if(languageb.equals("Norwegian")){
                    //Need to fix this!
            }
            if(languageb.equals("English")){
                    //Need to fix this!
            }
            if(storageb.equals("SD Card")){
               String sdStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PictureTalk/";
               FileInteraction fi = new FileInteraction();
               fi.firstTimeFillPath(getResources(), "PictureTalk/Food", sdStoragePath +"PictureTalk/Food");
               fi.firstTimeFillPath(getResources(), "PrivatePictures", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"PrivatePictures");
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenuActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("dataStorePath",sdStoragePath);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

My XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/languagetext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
    android:text="Choose language" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/languagetext"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/languagetext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/languageGroup">



    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/norwegianRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Norwegian" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/englishRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="English" />

</RadioGroup>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/internal_sd"
    android:layout_width="464dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
    android:text="Do you want to store the data to:" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/storageGroup">



    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/sdcardRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="SD card" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/internalRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Internal storage" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok"
    android:id="@+id/okBtn"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

Comment: I cant for the love of g** get the XML and Error log posted! Just get error of uncorrect formed code...

Comment: are you using fragments?

Comment: Not at this point. Its just supposed to be an inital activity running once if the user havent used the program before. The Intent further down goes to an Activity that uses fragments. Are you thinking about the onclick to View? Im pretty new to Android :P

Comment: post your entire main activity and xml. Can't help without that.

Comment: By framents I mean, is your code structured like this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html   ?

Comment: At that point in time there are no fragments, Fragments arent used until the next step when i use Intent to start MainMenuActivity which calls an Fragment instance that is replaced with other fragment throughout the app usage. Trying to get all the code posted, dunno why i keep getting error wrong formated,will keep trying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off with, what element is assigned the id `"@+id/languageGroup"` since it doesn't appear to be declared in your XML

Comment: The first RadioGroup has id languageGroup. EDIT, oh wait hmm. why is that set to layout_below (facepalm!)

Comment: Is this your entire XML code? Because nowhere do I see `android:id="@+id/languageGroup"` Yea that might be causing your problem

Comment: Omg it works, i cant believe it was such a stupid error, i mean ive stared blindely on my code for hours without seeing it...! Thanks:)